# OP_CHECKDATASIGVERIFY not working

Tags: bitcoin-cash, script, ecash

I'm trying to generate a signature and pass it through OP_CHECKDATASIGVERIFY as part of a P2SH address on a regtest network.  This results in the following:

**Public Key:**

```
036ab9012ecc30c30f9220d862a56c5c99b1a08d783be605406fbde8ece2807b2f
```

**Signature:**

```
304402200ac548d1e8b03c7d0bdfe4aedb4b13daacf2b1c2fa265afafae5d963d66a7fa702202cdb383bb3b4b4bc88403337fb2922f5166670c8bccf246e9bd5c963de93fae2
```

**Data Signed:**

```
7f7f9af76890ca09afc49e458a1b23fdd2e29cc061693c4b326b16e40728091a
```

Clientside (bitcore-lib-cash) says the signature validates and complies with the LowS check, but when submitted to the network the signature fails:

**bitcore-lib-cash** 0.19.0 => The signature can be verified

**Bitcoin-ABC** v190100 => `16: mandatory-script-verify-flag-failed (Signature must be zero for failed CHECK(MULTI)SIG operation)`

Debugging via bch-deb: https://hastebin.com/gelitojuge.rb

Is there anything that looks out of the ordinary here?

*UPDATE: 3/20/19 - note, this is a different, simplified full example tx*

**Raw TX:** There are extra variables being passed in, but only a couple are currently used.

```
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
```

**Script ASM:**

```
1feedf4d49945fdfeab9669032efc447ab0db6ae87369bbeca4994f9fc4dafc6be4b1c239d77ffb910df92b732858c9cc0687e44648a3b24bd0925b4a0d1266db3 02a4b770d3adf69c1c414d08eed6572e37bdfe956c8d35027550b2d0659cf78c88 0 0 8 3 3 3 3f8147b020f3351da2cf15f133eeb2d9da072443 0 OP_DUP OP_CHECKSEQUENCEVERIFY 20 OP_PICK OP_HASH256 13 OP_PICK OP_OVER 14 OP_PICK OP_CHECKDATASIGVERIFY
```

**Input Script Hash:**

```
bdb4b1cbd79af7137ff1771cea2c3f818bf35884962bbbea6013ec6c75b865b0
```

*UPDATE 3/23*

### Simplified TX with only data pushes, OP_CDSV, and OP_true: https://hastebin.com/raw/retabokura

Update 3/29/19: My signing process: https://hastebin.com/magehodufu.js

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about bitcoin.

Comment: On the contrary, markedly on topic: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Could you please post the transaction here?

Comment: Sure, but might be a couple hours until I can pull it together. Thanks for the response in advance.

Comment: I think this might be caused because of the SCRIPT_ERR_CLEANSTACK, because there aren't exactly one element in the end, but I'll look at it more detailedly tomorrow. I could get rid of the error by adding LOTS of `OP_DROP` and an `OP_1`.

Comment: I'll clean up the stack at the end and see if there's any difference on my end...odd that it would throw a CHECKSIG error though.  Thanks again.

Comment: Here's a new TX with the added drops.  Assuming that CHECKDATASIG pops three elements off, this should end up with a 1 on the stack: https://hastebin.com/raw/enohelegus (but still same result)

Comment: Just checking, but is it the case that your signature is missing a sighash flag at the end?

Comment: @UgamKamat I tried adding that, but throws "Non-canonical DER signature" error

Comment: OP_CHECKDATASIGVERIFY is correct, and your signature is wrong. It looks like you need help on fixing the signing process that you used, but you haven't included any information on your incorrect signing process.

Comment: @MarkLundeberg Here's my signing process: https://hastebin.com/magehodufu.js Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

checking from https://hastebin.com/raw/imodonelic

```
static void test_sig ( )
{
  const MyKey32 prv ( QByteArray::fromHex ( "39f8ca6c7e7c05aaf9c97e3253fd4c688730b4404d0f502441eb3aacea01b569" ) );
  const MyByteArray pub ( prv.getPublicKeyCompressed ( ) );
  const MyByteArray sig ( QByteArray::fromHex ( "3045022100aecf494d10f3696809972bad0546a7ea65802ebc40dd1f369185fd52eac016c902201b35692e40d6edb21c422a735f217d028da5f14447ccb31c27aec56ee26b426e" ) );
  const MyByteArray dat ( QByteArray::fromHex ( "0200000001f8f9599fc41346a68507bfbdb26b06af464d20ef709075660657b29b7bc6136c01000000000000000002d5b4eb050000000017a914064ebb4529c5cade492e1790ae1f19943e0c6bfd87d2100a000000000017a914064ebb4529c5cade492e1790ae1f19943e0c6bfd870000000001000000" ) );
  qDebug ( ) << "prv =" << prv.toHex ( ).constData ( );
  qDebug ( ) << "pub =" << pub.toHex ( ).constData ( );
  const MyKey32 digest ( dat.sha256d ( ) );
  qDebug ( ) << "hash=" << digest.toHex ( ).constData ( );
  qDebug ( ) << "your values=" << ( digest.verify ( pub, sig ) ? "passed" : "failed" );

// now create correct values

  const MyKey20 addr ( prv.getAddressHashCompressed ( ) );
  MyByteArray csig;
  MyByteArray cpub;
  prv.signHash ( addr, digest, csig, cpub );
  qDebug ( ) << "sig=" << csig.toHex ( ).constData ( );
  qDebug ( ) << "pub=" << cpub.toHex ( ).constData ( );
  qDebug ( ) << "my values=" << ( digest.verify ( cpub, csig ) ? "passed" : "failed" );
}
```

The output is:

```
prv = 39f8ca6c7e7c05aaf9c97e3253fd4c688730b4404d0f502441eb3aacea01b569
pub = 02118805dc4fc1bc36c86a606e760fcc3875e215b88306cca33cd549d3d5668339
hash= cc8fc76706ec95500d170cc01e915725e3c35979b00c27e8638b2ef3399f3ce1
your values= failed
sig= 30430220683555525c15dfc685580824d172890d16f24a996fa37ad4cd22d1a49ff61510021f60d78601ed827e0d46fe8043cbc36f054f4a9cb96c481714b8b6d21575d336
pub= 02118805dc4fc1bc36c86a606e760fcc3875e215b88306cca33cd549d3d5668339
my values= passed
```

Note: my code does not use dECDSA

Comment: Regarding not using ECDSA (I def am), is BCH on Schnorr sigs already (ABC 19)?

Comment: this is **ecdsa**. i mean that i do not use **deterministic** ecdsa, so you will not be able to reproduce the same **signature** byte-by-byte

Comment: Was finally able to get this working (unfortunately outside of the bounty limit).  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
static void test_sig ( )
{
  const MyByteArray pub ( QByteArray::fromHex ( "036ab9012ecc30c30f9220d862a56c5c99b1a08d783be605406fbde8ece2807b2f" ) );
  const MyByteArray sig ( QByteArray::fromHex ( "304402200ac548d1e8b03c7d0bdfe4aedb4b13daacf2b1c2fa265afafae5d963d66a7fa702202cdb383bb3b4b4bc88403337fb2922f5166670c8bccf246e9bd5c963de93fae2" ) );
  const MyKey32 hash ( MyKey32::fromHex ( "7f7f9af76890ca09afc49e458a1b23fdd2e29cc061693c4b326b16e40728091a" ) );
  qDebug ( ) << ( hash.verify ( pub, sig ) ? "passed" : "failed" );
}
```

The result of this code is `passed`

**But!** `OP_CHECKDATASIGVERIFY` needs the `data` itself, not a `hash` of it.

Comment: That hash of the scriptSig is what was originally signed (in order to mirror match OP_CHECKSIG's input). The scriptSig is the first value passed in, and get's hashed to match the value that was signed.  Looks like it might be my ABC.

Comment: Please, simplify your code. Remove OP_PICK, OP_OVER, OP_CSV and so on. Leave only push(signature) push(data) push(pubkey) OP_CHECKDATASIGVERIFY OP_TRUE. Note that `CLEAN_STACK` is mandatory rule for BCHABC

Comment: OK -- will do and return with results.  Thanks for the response.

Comment: I have simplified the code to only data pushes, CDSV and OP_TRUE: https://hastebin.com/raw/retabokura (same result) I do see now that ABC expects the data before the hash.

Answer (score 0):

```
static void test_sig ( )
{
  const MyByteArray pub ( QByteArray::fromHex ( "02118805dc4fc1bc36c86a606e760fcc3875e215b88306cca33cd549d3d5668339" ) );
  const MyByteArray sig ( QByteArray::fromHex ( "3045022100d06f815197d6a7af07e76ba312ab9496acb8aef3ec286098e123c26ce610e4950220547c84f3292b4f1be91ed0a0745c74c4622e3e2aa400e8f2de6d32aacbf7c591" ) );
  const MyByteArray dat ( QByteArray::fromHex ( "0200000001f8f9599fc41346a68507bfbdb26b06af464d20ef709075660657b29b7bc6136c01000000000000000002d5b4eb050000000017a914f60ae3ea9b07c104627a98f9bc03e7268f77a58d87d2100a000000000017a914f60ae3ea9b07c104627a98f9bc03e7268f77a58d870000000001000000" ) );
  const MyKey32 digest ( dat.sha256d ( ) );
  qDebug ( ) << ( digest.verify ( pub, sig ) ? "passed" : "failed" );
}
```

The result is `failed`. Your data is not valid for `OP_CDSV` opcode

Comment: Thanks for sticking with this: I'm beginning to think the issue is in how i'm generating the double-sha256.  The following includes both the Data as submitted and the hash as signed: https://hastebin.com/raw/izefekopej.  Bitcore-lib-cash continues to report that the sig is valid.

Comment: The signature can be valid, but not for these pubkey `and` message :)

Answer (score 0):

values from https://hastebin.com/raw/izefekopej

```
static void test_sig ( )
{
  const MyKey32 prv ( QByteArray::fromHex ( "0b08a58dd052baad2f342779271b0c8ef92273632dd630b3e1627fdac0e77963" ) );
  const MyByteArray pub ( prv.getPublicKeyCompressed ( ) );
  qDebug ( ) << pub.toHex ( ).constData ( );
}
```

The output is: `028b00a221a20da77938bacdd793b569728ff4974eeb6c496f30d90128ba939359` while expected is `02118805dc4fc1bc36c86a606e760fcc3875e215b88306cca33cd549d3d5668339`

Your public key `02118805d...` does not match your private key `0b08a58dd052...`

You can easy check it on https://www.bitaddress.org/

Comment: Shoot...I miss-copied the Private Key..should have been 39f8ca6c7e7c05aaf9c97e3253fd4c688730b4404d0f502441eb3aacea01b569.  Corrected paste: https://hastebin.com/raw/imodonelic (everything else is the same and private key checks out with bitaddress).